# Openshift: Unable to connect to mysql using localhost

Tags: mysql, openshift

Trying to deploy my application on Openshift jboss/mysql gear. My hibernate.cfg.xml contains localhost/db_name as hibernate.connection.url. I would like to maintain it. But hibernate is  unable to connect. If I explicitly mention bind_address that I see in my.cnf it works as expected.

Any idea, how can I map my localhost to that bind address? I can't edit my.cnf on Openshift.

Comment: `localhotst` or `localhost`?

Comment: @pala_  typo, updated.

Comment: if you change it to `127.0.0.1/db_name` instead, does it work?

Comment: whats the `bind_address` value in my.cnf?

Comment: but not 127.0.0.1? if so thats why localhost isn't working. it'd be set in your system hosts file to point to 127.0.0.1

Comment: @pala_yes, not 127.0.0.1

Comment: Yeah then you're stuck with either a) updating your connection url, or b) updating your system hosts file to point localhost to the bind address.  I probably wouldn't recommend that tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the MySQL environment variables, not "localhost", as your MySQL instance is not listening on localhost.  Refer to these two articles on OpenShift environment variables, and mysql in general, they should help you get your application running.

https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html
https://developers.openshift.com/en/databases-mysql.html